# Segmentation Fault on C Cause Of fgetc()

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to coding a pathfinding algorithm in C. I'm trying to scan the map in which I'm trying to find the shortest path, and I'm putting it into a 2D dynamic array.

This is my basic map :

```
5 5
11111
01001
00101
00010
00001
```

5 is row count and other 5 is column count. And 1 is way, 0 is wall.
This is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int row;
int column;

void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int **array;
    fp = fopen("file.path", "r");
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &row);
    fgetc(fp);
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &column);
    array = (int **)malloc(row * sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
        array[i] = malloc(column * sizeof(int));

    for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<column; j++)
        {
            char tmp = fgetc(fp);
            array[i][j] = (tmp - '0');
        }
    }
}
```

and this code returning segmentation fault.

Comment: Do you really need a multi-dimensional array? Many times a single-dimensional array of size *M x N* is entirely sufficient, and from there you can emulate the 2D structure using row/column type offset calculations.

Comment: You should check whether `fopen` succeeds or not

Comment: Consider using a debugger (`gdb` is excellent, or whatever your IDE has built-in is probably good enough) to step through the program.

Comment: `array = malloc(row * sizeof(int *));`

Comment: `array = malloc(row * sizeof *array);` and `array[i] = malloc(column * sizeof *array[i]);` and remember to `free()` the resources when you no longer need them.

Comment: In addition to the above suggestions, assuming that fp is not NULL, the line `fscanf("%d %d", &row, &column);` would read in the first line of the file.  I also recommend immediately printing out everything that you read in, so that you can make sure that you're getting what you think you're getting.

Comment: Don't cast the result returned from `malloc()` etc.; and `main()` returns `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this code returning segmentation fault.

see the remark about *malloc* below

---

Some remarks from top to bottom of your code

In

> ```
> int row;
> int column;
> ```

why these two global variables ? they can be local in *main*

In

> ```
> fp = fopen("file.path", "r");
> fscanf(fp, "%d", &row);
> fgetc(fp);
> fscanf(fp, "%d", &column);
> ```

you need to check *fp* is not NULL to be sure the open success

you need to check the *fscanf* returns 1 to be sure you was able to read a number

the *fgetc* between them is useless, the space will be bypassed by the second *fscanf*

note you can do a unique *fscanf* to read the two numbers :

```
if (fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &row, &column) != 2) {
  ... manage error to not continue the execution
}
```

In

> ```
>  array = (int **)malloc(row * sizeof(int));
> ```

as it is said in remarks you allocate an array of `int*` not an array of *int*, that explain your segmentation fault later in the execution (you are visibly in 64b), the cast is useless, so `array = malloc(row * sizeof(int*));`

You need also to check malloc does not return NULL

In

```
       char tmp = fgetc(fp);
        array[i][j] = (tmp - '0');
```

*tmp* must be an *int* to be able to check the EOF case

Note you can also read a string rather than character by character

Warning currently *tmp* get the newlines so you initialize wrongly the array

---

A proposal :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int ** array;
    int row;
    int column;

    fp = fopen("file.path", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
      puts("cannot open file.path");
      return -1;
    }

    if (fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &row, &column) != 2) {
      puts("cannot read row column");
      fclose(fp);
      return -1;
    }

    array = malloc(row * sizeof(int*));

    if (array == NULL) {
      puts("not enough memory");
      fclose(fp);
      return -1;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<row; i++) {
      array[i] = malloc(column * sizeof(int));
      if (array[i] == NULL) {
        puts("not enough memory");
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
      }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
      /* finish to read previous line */
      int c;

      while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != '\n') {
        if (c == EOF) {
          fclose(fp);
          puts("unexpected EOF");
          return -1;
        }
      }

      for(int j=0; j<column; j++)
      {
        c = fgetc(fp);

        if (c == EOF) {
          puts("unexpected EOF");
          fclose(fp);
          return -1;
        }
        if ((c != '0') && (c != '1')) {
          puts("invalid value");
          fclose(fp);
        }

        array[i][j] = (c - '0');
      }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    /* show the content for at least debug */
    puts("array is:");

    for (int i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
      for (int j=0; j<column; j++)
        printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
      putchar('\n');
    }

    /* free resources */
    for (int i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
      free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra b.c
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat file.path 
5 5
11111
01001
00101
00010
00001
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./a.out
array is:
1 1 1 1 1 
0 1 0 0 1 
0 0 1 0 1 
0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 1 
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Execution under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ valgrind ./a.out
==4841== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4841== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4841== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4841== Command: ./a.out
==4841== 
array is:
1 1 1 1 1 
0 1 0 0 1 
0 0 1 0 1 
0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 1 
==4841== 
==4841== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4841==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4841==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 5,592 bytes allocated
==4841== 
==4841== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4841== 
==4841== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4841== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

Note : I use *fscanf* then *fgetc* and because of the mix it is necessary to manage the newline, an other way is to always use *getline* to read line per line and for the dims to use *sscanf*

Answer (score 0):

It compiles and runs in my test (using VC++ 2017) without a segfault, you need to run it in a debugger to determine where and why it is failing on your target.

However the code is incorrect or ill-advised in a number of ways that your should correct in any case.

- It will fail to allocate the correct amount of space on a target where `sizeof(int) != sizeof(int*)`.
- Your map will be loaded incorrectly as you have not dealt with the newline characters including the one after the first `5 5` line.
- The `fgetc(fp);` between the two `fscanf`, it serves no purpose since `fscanf()` will discard leading whitespace in any case.
- `row` and `column` are unnecessarily global.
- You have no error checking whatsoever.
- In C casting `malloc()` is not required or advised.

Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("file.path", "r") ;

    if( fp != 0 )
    {
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;
        int check = fscanf( fp, "%d%d\n", &row, &column ) ;

        if( check == 2 )
        {
            bool map_valid = false;
            int** array = malloc( row * sizeof(*array) ) ;
            if( array != NULL )
            {   
                map_valid = true ;
                for( int i = 0; map_valid && i < row ; i++ )
                {
                    array[i] = malloc( column * sizeof(*array[i]) ) ;
                    map_valid = (array[i] != NULL) ;
                }
            }

            for( int i = 0; map_valid && i < row; i++ )
            {
                int c = 0 ;
                for( int j = 0; map_valid && j < column; j++ )
                {
                    c = fgetc(fp);
                    map_valid = c != EOF ;
                    array[i][j] = (c - '0');
                }
                    while( map_valid  && (c = fgetc(fp)) != '\n' && c != EOF ){}
            }

            if( map_valid )
            {
                // ...
            }

            if( array != NULL )
            {
                for( int i  = 0; i < row; i++ )
                {
                    if( array[i] != NULL )
                    {
                        free( array[i] ) ;
                    }
                }
                free( array ) ;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```